# mapquest cache geocoding result for later use with googlemaps

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, mapquest

Can I store/cache result of geocoding via mapquest in mt own DB?

I want to retrive Latitude/Longitude via mapquest save in my DB and those coordinates 
later on for geofencing and show some result in googlemaps.

Comment: do you use licensed or open geocoding?

Comment: I am using open geocoding.

Comment: The results may be stored(the data are free to use), when you print them you must also show the credits, see [**Terms of use**](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/geocoding-service#aui-3-2-0PR1-1150) and  [**License**](http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright)